# Modifying cursor property for select portion of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML that renders a simple arrow sign pointing towards the right:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { width: 0px; height: 0px; border-left: 20px solid black; border-top: 20px solid transparent; border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid transparent; position: absolute; left: 35px; top: 53px; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you hover of it, the cursor turns to pointer. But because it is actually a square `div`, the cursor turns pointer even if you are just outside the arrow within the perimeter of the `div`.

So I wrote this Javascript addition such that the cursor turns pointer only when the mouse is hovering over that arrow. For this purpose, I figured the coordinates of the three vertices of the triangle from Firebug (`(35,53)`,`(55,73)`,`(35,93)` clockwise from top). Then I check whether the point in question lies inside the triangle formed by these 3 vertices. This I do by checking whether the point and the opposite vertex for each edge lies on the same side of that edge or not (if they do, the product of the values obtained by substituting  the coordinates of that point for `x` and `y`  in that equation will be positive).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { width: 0px; height: 0px; border-left: 20px solid black; border-top: 20px solid transparent; border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid transparent; position: absolute; left: 35px; top: 53px;  }
.hoverclass { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function(e) { alert(e.pageX + " " + e.pageY); });
function l1(x,y) { return y - x - 18; }
function l2(x,y) { return x+y-128; }
function l3(x,y) { return x-35; }
$("div").hover(function(e) {
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;
if (l1(x,y)*l1(35,93) >= 0 && l1(x,y)*l1(35,93) >= 0 && l1(x,y)*l1(35,93) >= 0 ) {
$(this).addClass('hoverclass');
}
else { $(this).removeClass('hoverclass'); }
},
function() {
$(this).removeClass('hoverclass');
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the results are not predictable. Sometimes the cursor turns pointer within the triangle only, sometimes outside as well (just as before), and sometimes not at all. I suspect that this is probably due to the `hover` function working overtime, that may be temporarily hanging the script. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Use SVG to create the arrow. You can then assign the CSS to that shape and it will work as you need. RaphaelJS would be a good library to use.

Comment: Oh no, I have absolutely no knowledge about either! Is there no good-old jQuery/CSS way?

Comment: Not really, as you've seen HTML containers are always rectangular. An Image map may work, but it's a very antiquated method of doing anything.

Comment: Yeah that's why I discarded the idea of image-map just after I though about it...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not quite true. You can make any shape have cursor pointer with CSS only. See this demo: http://cssdesk.com/PaB5n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done using HTML5 canvas. Basic idea is to check for pixel color on mousemove on canvas element. This way, your element can be of any form as you wish. Of course, you should make some optimization of following code:

[SEE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n4V7T/2/)

```
 function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

// set up triangle
var example = document.getElementById('example');
var context = example.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle   = '#000';
context.strokeStyle = '#f00';
context.lineWidth   = 1;

context.beginPath();
// Start from the top-left point.
context.moveTo(10, 10); // give the (x,y) coordinates
context.lineTo(60, 60);
context.lineTo(10, 120);
context.lineTo(10, 10);

// Done! Now fill the shape, and draw the stroke.
// Note: your shape will not be visible until you call any of the two methods.
context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

$('#example').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if(p[3]!='0') $(this).css({cursor:'pointer'});
    else $(this).css({cursor:'default'});
});
```

Comment: Wow, that looks promising. Can you add some comments to the code so that I can understand it better?

Comment: The code is quite simple by its own, you should look at HTML5 canvas or ask if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: Simple: on mousemove over canvas, you check for pixel color at cursor position. If color is different than default color (here white but you could config it depending of which color is your background color), then set cursor:pointer, else set it default.

Comment: What is assigned to `var p` and `var hex` towards the end?

Comment: p is for pixel, this is the method to get rgb pixel from HTML5 canvas. hex is just use for convenance to parse it to corresponding hexadecimal value.

Comment: Well, that's awesome. Thanks. This definitely calls for a bounty. Will start one tomorrow!

Comment: Just another question, I didn't understand your `rgbToHex` function, particularly what you are trying to do with all those bit shifting. What if I want to modify it to make it work for `fillStyle` as black?

Comment: You are correct, buggy if black color is used to fill element as hex conversion returning transparent as black. So solution seems to check if color is not transparent. Pixel four p[3] returns 0 for transparent color, see updated answer. Note than this no more need of hex conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use CSS instead. With :before and :after pseudo classes you can do magic. Check out this [Pure CSS GUI icons](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/)  by Nicolas Gallagher.

If you use any CSS pre-processor, these icons can be wrapped up as a mixin, this way required properties can be assigned like this:

```
#icon > .close(16px, #fff, #E83921);
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can make any shape have cursor pointer with CSS only. The idea is to rotate wrapper container which has `overflow: hidden` (you can have several of them depending on the shape you need). In case of OP problem this code does a trick:

```
<div class="arrow"><i></i></div>

.arrow {
  margin: 100px;
  border_: 1px red solid;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow i {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  background-color: green;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -35px 0 0 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

See this demo: http://cssdesk.com/PaB5n

True that this requires CSS transform support so it's not cross browser.

Comment: Wow. That looks cool. Can you please explain in a bit more detail your logic?

Comment: Really interesting, unfortunately, doesn't work on IE<10 as you mentionned it