# make a triangle div to hold text and close on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make a fixed triangle div hold text and images?

Also what I did was [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/nS9Bm/) but here when the div is open on hover, and when I hover out, it doesn't close as the div is in a square shape, So what I need to do so the moment user hovers out, the div should be closed?

jQuery will be fine too

CSS

```
.map {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #ff0000;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -440px;
}

.map:hover {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[**Another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nS9Bm/1/)

Comment: This is already the case: when mouse is out div closed. Problem is what you want is triggering mouse out when mouse cursor is no more over red zone. See similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315795/modiying-cursor-property-for-select-portion-of-an-element/

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element in chrome for example, youu ll see that altho you use borders to create this trick div remains a square and when you hover over it covers the bottom left 500x500 pixels

You might want to consider tracking the mouse coords in order to achieve what you want.

```
$(".map").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```

Comment: Exactly, I don't want the div to pop up unless and until I take my mouse to that and same goes for closing