# jQuery offsetparent returns non-positioned parent also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying out the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").click(function(){
    alert($(this).offsetParent().length);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p><span>Click me away!</span></p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

From the jQuery documentation, `offsetParent()` is supposed to return the closest positioned parent, **positioned** meaning one with `position` defined explicitly as 'static`,`absolute`or`relative`. here, none is declared for any element, yet the alert pops up 1. How come?

Comment: You mean `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. Do you have CSS? Is there any more code?

Comment: No there isn't. That's my point, there is no `position` property defined for any element in my file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let as look at the return result:

```
[html, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: span, jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

So for `$(span).offsetParent()` you get the `HTML` element.

Now let's look at the implementation of `offsetParent`:

```
offsetParent: function() {
    return this.map(function() {
        var offsetParent = this.offsetParent || document.documentElement;
        while ( offsetParent && ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent, "html" ) && jQuery.css( offsetParent, "position") === "static" ) ) {
            offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
        }
        return offsetParent || document.documentElement;
    });
}
```

From the code above we see that if we don't have positioned parent `offsetParent` returns the `HTML` element.

The only bad things is that when I looked at the documentation that wasn't there.

To check whether there's actually an `offsetParent` you can use:

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0] === $(elem).offsetParent()[0]`

Comment: Then, how do we check if an element has an ``offsetparent()` or not. I am using GWT, so I can't do a Javascript like check like `if ($(elem).offsetParent())`. How to change it to a Boolean type of checking?

Comment: You can check like this: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0] === $(elem).offsetParent()[0]`

Comment: Can you then tell me how does the `findPos` function in the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315795/modiying-cursor-property-for-select-portion-of-an-element works?

Comment: It looks through all positioned parents of given node and sums their coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, but when does the loop end? Even `$("html").offsetparent().length` returns 1..

Comment: Look at the first line of the implementation `var offsetParent = this.offsetParent || document.documentElement;`. It returns `document.documentElement`

Comment: Can't the `findPos` be replaced by something like `e.pageX() - $(elem).offset().left`? I mean, is there no jQuery way to do it instead of resorting to native Javascript methods?

Comment: Yes it can. First you should check whether your element is positioned and after that use `$(elem).offset().left`

Comment: Yeah, it's positioned. So `e.pageX() - $(elem).offset().left` should work?

Comment: Yes for finding the relative position of event coordinates (probably click) this should work.

Comment: A slightly more efficient comparison than searching for elements with name "html" is... `offsetParent[0].nodeName == "HTML"`